# include in git repo, but not in npm package

Tags: node.js, git

I have a project containing a .gitignore file. This is currently being used to exclude certain files from *both* the git repo and the npm package that comes out of `npm pack`.

Let's say I have a file `foo.txt` which I want to commit to the git repo, but exclude from the npm package. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.npmignore` file included at the root of the project. 
It's syntax is similar to `.gitignore`'s one. For more info visit
[.npmignore documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers#keeping-files-out-of-your-package) .